# If statements inside of constructors

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement, constructor, boolean

I have a class called with an empty constructor and I want to have an if statement that sets a Boolean to `true` if the constructor has been used in an instantiation of that class. For example:

```
public class Test {
public float a1;
public int b1;
public double c1;
public Boolean ifConsUsed = false;

public Test(float a, int b, double c, Main app) {
   a1 = a; b1 = b; c1 = c; applet = app;
      if(expression goes here) {
      ifConsUsed = true;
      }
   }
```

}

In this instance what expression would I put into the if statement to detect if the constructor was used?

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  If the code inside the constructor is running, then the constructor has been called.  So you don't need an if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the constructor runs , it itself means that an object has been instantiated.
The constructor of a class is called it itself means that the object has been created. So, keep it simply..

```
public class Test 
{
    public float a1;
    public int b1;
    public double c1;
    public Boolean ifConsUsed = false;

    public Test(float a, int b, double c, Main app)
   {
        a1 = a; b1 = b; c1 = c; applet = app;
        ifConsUsed = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any condition to set `ifConsUsed` if your intention is just to figure out that if constructor is called or not

```
 public Test(float a, int b, double c, Main app) {
      ifConsUsed = true;
       ....
         }
```